# Remote Installation on Dedicated Server

Tags: remote, dedicated-server

I have a question in my mind. I am reselling dedicated server from OVH and Server4you. I have notice that they have remote installtion feature. Only we need to select which os we want to install and the installation start automaticly. Can you someone tell me how they do this? if it is a dedicated server then how they install os template into a dedicated server hard disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably select your installation, then configuration for PXE booting is changed and the server is configured to start from network, loads the installer and that's it.